# Python beautifulSoup scraping dropdowns

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the search result on this link: https://www.inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/ which requires that I select a dropdown value and then another shows up which I have to select from before searching. I am able to get the values from the first dropdown selection but not from the others. Here's what I have currently:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base = 'https://www.inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/'

base_req = requests.get(base, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup( base_req.text, "html.parser" )

# states
states = soup.find('select', id = "statePoll")

stateItems = states.select('option[value]')

stateValues = [ stateItem.text for stateItem in stateItems ]


# print(stateValues)

lgas = soup.find('select', id = "lgaPoll")

lgaItems = lgas.select('option[value]')

lgaValues = [ lgaItem.text for lgaItem in lgaItems ]


print(lgas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can't get those values by scraping the HTML on that page. The page uses JavaScript to request the options from another page and dynamically insert them into the page. You will have to use the information you can scrape to make such requests yourself. Here is an example of how to get the next step that should show you the general idea:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base = 'https://www.inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/'
lga_view = 'https://www.inecnigeria.org/wp-content/themes/independent-national-electoral-commission/custom/views/lgaView.php'
base_req = requests.get(base, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(base_req.text, "html.parser" )

states = soup.find('select', id = "statePoll")
state_options = states.find_all('option')
states = {opt.text: int(opt['value']) for opt in state_options if 'value' in opt.attrs}

lga = {k: requests.post(lga_view, {'state_id': v}, verify=False).json() for k,v in states.items()}

print(lga)
```

Comment: Hi @ahnlabb Sorry I am just returning to this but I used a similar approach to scrape the ward view and not getting expected output.

```python

ward_view = 'https://www.inecnigeria.org/wp-content/themes/independent-national-electoral-commission/custom/views/wardView.php'


wards = {}


for key, value in lgas.items():
    for k, v in value.items(): # lgas: id, name, abbreviation, state_id
        perm = requests.post(ward_view, { 'lga_id': value, 'state_id': v['state_id'] }, verify=False).json()
        wards[key] = perm

print(wards)

```